# Clarification VS Solutions and Web Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have difficulties to understand some concept in VS.

My aim is to develop a simple WebSite. Website will have two main section: CMS and a BLOG.

I would like develop CMS and BLOG as different Web Projects in different time.
Now I understand in VS I can have a single Web Solution where I can place both Web Projects.

What I do not understand is what is happening at the moment of deployment and using the website.

Lets imagine file structure:

- WebSolutions
  default.aspx

  - Cms
    cms.aspx
  - Blog
    blog.aspx

When I deploy the entire solution the User can visit default.aspx and after use application as WebSolutions/Cms/cms.aspx ???

I hope it make sense, I have problem even to explain it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a structure like this:

- / (root)
- /CMS/
- /BLOG/
- default.aspx

Within the CMS and BLOG directory add a default.aspx file as well.

Then you simply access the other areas by going to [domain]/CMS/default.aspx or [domain]/BLOG/default.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jack, in case i use a SOLUTION in VS. How shluld be organized? thanks

Comment: You can organize it the same way.  The structure will only change drastically if you switch to something like MVC.